# Start Engine If Battery Drops Below "X" Volts

Tags: battery, starting, remote-start, voltage

I use a lot of devices in my work vehicle that are typically running when the engine is off. I was doing some reading into ways to maintain battery voltage and I read that there was a device that would start the engine to charge the battery if the voltage dropped below a preset amount. I've tried some Googling and haven't found any such device. Has anyone heard of something like this?

Comment: I believe that you are referring to the newly popular LITHIUM ION PORTABLE BATTERY CHARGER/BOOSTER. They're quite expensive though but would indeed come in handy in your situation.

Comment: This is supposed to be an add on device similar to a remote starter. Something that is wired in and left alone. Are these chargers/boosters like this?

Comment: Another option would be to replace the battery with something like an OPTIMA YELLOW TOP AGM DEEP CYCLE BATTERY. Which deep cycle batteries are designed for constant drainage of power with or without the engine running.

Comment: It's nothing like remote start at all. What I'm talking about is like a booster box that someone would use to jump  start a car with. But the new lithium ones are much smaller, lighter, and much more powerful and in such a small package and doesn't require being charged nearly as often as traditional boosters.

Comment: I've been looking into that. I'm planning on building a small battery bank so I can run approximately 1000watts of electronics for a day or so without fully draining batteries.

Comment: I did find this device and it sounds similar to my original post but it doesn't make any mention about being used in an application such as what I described although it may be one of the user downloadable features. http://www.uniquetruck.com/p-23412-battery-brain-t3-dual-remote-reconnectdisconnect.aspx?affiliateID=10056&gclid=CK6ej4fx8c4CFZSBaQodWgUJjw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44853/discussion-between-trigga-and-jesse-elser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QW1YFJI)?

The key to this is you're looking for a remote starter which *happens* to provide a low battery protection option. You *must* have remote start to do what you're asking, and honestly once that's addressed it really isn't a big stretch to add low-voltage protection.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to find. Thanks 

Answer (score 2):

Just my thought, but I have a similar issue on my race car trailer, which has a huge inverter which runs lights, an air conditioner, a microwave, a refigerator (frozen burritos and healthy hydration liquids) and the DVD player.

(These things are *essential* when racing a vintage car.  *Say nothing!*)

My actual point is, I have a bank of 3 deep-cycle batteries in the trailer, that charge on the tows to-and-fro from an 8-gauge wire from the diesel tractor.  They can also charge from a Honda genset if I throw the right switches.

The beauty is, I bought this "battery isolater" thing, so that even when I am too cool and eat too many burritos and watch too many DVDs, it doesn't kill the tractor (actually just a Ford F350) battery and prevent a start on a cold morning.

So, I'm thinking if you can find a place (trunk maybe?) for just *one* small RV type deep cycle battery (aka RV terms "house battery"), and get one of these battery isolator thingamajiggies, you can do all your "device" stuff all day long with zero risk of having to call AAA or not getting home.

The "device" [house] battery will be recharged by the vehicle alternator.  Most of the "thingamawhatsis" also have a bypass switch that allows starting assistance if the "tractor" battery dies from lights left on, etc.

I can't remember what the brand of my battery isolator is, but I can certainly tell you the place to find this kind of information is in an RV forum.  These folks deal with exactly this issue all the time.

In the long run I think this a more prudent and cost-effective solution than having some computer decide when to start your vehicle on a whim.  The wiring is simpler and the result much more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

We've been having this technology in our 18 wheelers for years I don't know where you can find it for regular vehicles my 18 wheeler now has it I have a  2016 Freightliner Cascadia..  another place where I saw this technology I was surfing on YouTube and ran across it on an RV, on a dodge pro master chassis..  ironically I have a 2018.pro master and I have been looking for that damn video every sense... because I need it for my pro master and I don't remember what RV company had it .

Answer (score 0):

They make exactly what you are looking for in motor homes also.  Check out this video.  I would love to know the parts list to figure out a DIY option as well.

https://youtu.be/QCGzJ9U-G_M

Joe

Comment: It would be helpful if you were able to provide an outline on what is featured in this video, in case the link/video is taken town in the future.